# Por que no Dart o comando print([1] == [1]) retorna false?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  print([1] == [1]);
}
```

[O código acima no DartPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdNA6.png)

Comment: ele compara se o mesmo objeto aponta para o mesmo endereço de memoria, como é duas lista cada uma aponta para endereços diferentes são objetos diferente então retorna `false`

Comment: esta comparando a referências e não o conteúdo se fosse o conteudo poderia usar o `listEquals`  pergunta ampla sem muito detalhes ai fica essas duas questão quer comparar a referencia ou conteudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[1]` indica ser um *array*, certo? E *arrays* são objetos por referência. Ou seja, o conteúdo que está usando ali é um endereço de memória que aponta para o local onde efetivamente está o objeto que te interessa, portanto o seu objeto principal é uma referência para o objeto secundário que é o que importa e que está vendo e acha que está sendo comparado.

Mas a comparação está sendo feita com o objeto principal, que é um ponteiro, um endereço de memória. O primeiro *array* foi alocado na memória e obteve um endereço para referenciá-lo. O segundo *array* também foi alocado na memória em outro local, portanto outro endereço.

Entendeu que está comparando dois endereços diferentes? Não está comparando o conteúdo do *array*, até porque potencialmente poderia ser enorme e potencialmente teria que percorrer todo o *array* para descobrir se ele é igual por completo. Se quer isso, você tem que criar um algoritmo que faça isso. Pode ser um laço que verifique todos os elementos até achar um que não seja igual, aí sabe que é diferente, ou pode usar algo mais pronto como o [`ListEquality`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListEquality-class.html) do Flutter.

Comment: Muito obrigado!